# Which Linux os and web server used

Tags: magento-1.9

We are using our Magento site in webhosting company but due to traffic we facing low performance so we planning to install on VPS so i am confused and need some suggestion.

1) Which Linux OS need to use (Centos or Ubuntu) for best performance ?
2) 32bit or 64bit make any effect on performance ?
3) Which web server use apache2 or nginx ?
4) Which Mysql version ?
5) As i know .htaccess not support on nginx so if we use nginx we need to edit nginx.conf but any change required on nginx.conf if we add any extension on Magento ?

Comment: `32bit or 64bit `  omg you need to hire magento system admin...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's hard to find silver bullet answers. So will try to share my experience and hope my answer will help you.
First of all, I think you need to estimate what amount of resources you need for your Magento instance and locate weak points of your server.
Then calculate what server you need. Professional sys admin can do this for you. And you can use load testing tools, Jmeter or Gatling for example to check if calculations and assumptions where right. You will know limits of your server too, so can plan new upgrade when reach them.

1) Centos or Ubuntu doesn't metter, have seen dosens configurations
    on both OS, more important how it's configured and tuned.

2) Linux distributions can recompile the open-source software for 64-bit
    CPUs, so I don't think now you will have difference comparing to 32bit systems, may be only on old processors.

3) You can use both Nginx or Apache, or Apache for dynamic and Nginx for static content. Apache a little bit stable, Nginx a little bit faster as I seen. Latest versions both have good results. I personally prefer Nginx + php-fpm setup.

4) Latest stable MySQL usually is better. I've chose Percona over MySQL

5) Usually you don't need to change Nginx configuration when you install extensions, only in cases when this extension requires server module, or you need tune something.

There are a lot of tools that can help you to boost your server performance: Redis, Varnish, CDN, proper scaling and so on. 
 You can check Magento hosting partners in the [catalog](http://partners.magento.com/partner_locator/search.aspx?l=All&r=All&t=HostingPartners) to see what they use, or what is better chose one of them for your site. From my experience companies specializing on Magento much better than common hosting providers and can tune everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on your load for frontend and admin. i.e do you have alot of customers on your site at same time and also do you have some resource draining admin functions that regularly occur throughout the business day?

All these factor into your setup especially for the apache and nginx / varnish setup.

As for OS, i would go for Centos 64bit. mysql - use whatever your php version is max supported to (this depends also on what version of magento you use as later php versions are not supported by alot of the community editions and even enterprise up to 1.13.